# Activating 2012r2 Standard Eval using 2016 Downgrade Rights

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

What do I need to activate 2012r2 Eval using a 2016 license? Is there a separate key, or do I need to specify a special "edition" in my DISM command? I can't seem to find much online about it, and I am hoping that this is possible with the Eval install.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, there is a separate key to use.